# CycleSort in Haskell - troubles

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell, cycle-sort

I am trying to make a CycleSort in Haskell, it is my assignment, but nobody has made me clear how to work with Haskell, I have tried many times, tried to "translate" a code from other language, but it didn't work. I have looked for it everywhere, but there was nothing. I would be very, very thankful if somebody helps me with this stuff.
There is the code of CycleSort in Java.

```
// Function sort the array using Cycle sort
public static void cycleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    // count number of memory writes
    int writes = 0;

    // traverse array elements and put it to on
    // the right place
    for (int cycle_start = 0; cycle_start <= n - 2; cycle_start++) {
        // initialize item as starting point
        int item = arr[cycle_start];

        // Find position where we put the item. We basically
        // count all smaller elements on right side of item.
        int pos = cycle_start;
        for (int i = cycle_start + 1; i < n; i++)
            if (arr[i] < item)
                pos++;

        // If item is already in correct position
        if (pos == cycle_start)
            continue;

        // ignore all duplicate elements
        while (item == arr[pos])
            pos += 1;

        // put the item to it's right position
        if (pos != cycle_start) {
            int temp = item;
            item = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = temp;
            writes++;
        }

        // Rotate rest of the cycle
        while (pos != cycle_start) {
            pos = cycle_start;

            // Find position where we put the element
            for (int i = cycle_start + 1; i < n; i++)
                if (arr[i] < item)
                    pos += 1;

            // ignore all duplicate elements
            while (item == arr[pos])
                pos += 1;

            // put the item to it's right position
            if (item != arr[pos]) {
                int temp = item;
                item = arr[pos];
                arr[pos] = temp;
                writes++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit off topic here. You can for example ask questions about *specific* parts of cyclesorts, and why your attempt to implement such subparts fail.

Comment: This would maybe be better suited to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AJFarmar, this isn't even *close* to being on-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to translate, let's go to [wikipedia's
definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort#Algorithm):

> ## Algorithm
>
> Given an element a, we can find the index at which it will occur in
> the sorted list by simply counting the number of elements in the entire list
> that are smaller than a. Now
>
> 1. If the element is already at the correct position, do nothing.
> 2. If it is not, we will write it to its intended position. That position is
>    inhabited by a different element b, which we then have to move to its
>    correct position. This process of displacing elements to their correct
>    positions continues until an element is moved to the original position of
>    a. This completes a cycle.
>
> Repeating this process for every element sorts the list, with a single writing
> operation if and only if an element is not already at its correct position.
> While computing the correct positions takes O(n) time for every single
> element, thus resulting in a quadratic time algorithm, the number of writing
> operations is minimized.
>
> ### Implementation
>
> To create a working implementation from the above outline,
> two issues need to be addressed:
>
> 1. When computing the correct positions, we have to make sure not to
>    double-count the first element of the cycle.
> 2. If there are duplicate elements present, we could try to move an element a
>    to its correct position, which already happens to be inhabited by an a.
>    Simply swapping these would cause the algorithm to cycle indefinitely.
>    Instead, we have to insert the element after any of its duplicates.

Implementing `cycleSort` in haskell, our first question should be what should
the type of `cycleSort` be?

The normal
[`sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort)
has the type `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`, but this won't work for `cycleSort`.
Cycle sort is an *in-place* algorithm, so sorting a list makes no sense. Rather,
we'll want to sort a [mutable
vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#t:MVector).

```
cycleSort :: Ord a => MVector s a -> MVector s a
```

This type isn't quite right though. Operations on `MVector`s aren't pure - they
return actions in some monad, usually `ST s` or `IO`. So this type needs a
little tweaking.

Rather than return a sorted vector, we'll return an action that will sort the
mutable vector when executed:

```
cycleSort :: (PrimMonad m, Ord a) => MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
```

(`PrimMonad m` just means that `m` can construct actions that mutate vectors,
`PrimState m` serves to tie the `MVector` to this particular monad).

For comparison with other implementations, we may want to count the number of
writes:

```
cycleSort :: (PrimMonad m, Ord a) => MVector (PrimState m) a -> m Int
```

So now we can work on the algorithm itself.

Since this is an assignment, I won't provide the solution for you, but here's
some useful functions:

- `Data.Vector.Mutable.length :: MVector s a -> Int` to get the length of a mutable vector
- `Data.Vector.Mutable.read :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m a` to read a value at an index in a mutable vector
- `Data.Vector.Mutable.write :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a -> m ()` to write a value at an index in a mutable vector

For an example of use, here's a function that reverses an MVector:

```
import Control.Monad (when)
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimMonad, PrimState)
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

reverseMVector :: PrimMonad m => MV.MVector (PrimState m) a -> m ()
reverseMVector v = loop 0 (MV.length v - 1) where
  loop lo hi = when (lo < hi) $ do
    a <- MV.read v lo
    b <- MV.read v hi
    MV.write v lo b
    MV.write v hi a
    loop (lo+1) (hi-1)
```

There's a bunch of advanced techniques that can make the solution prettier, but
recursive functions (like `loop` above) are sufficient.

For example, one could translate

```
// ignore all duplicate elements
while (item == arr[pos])
    pos += 1;
```

As

```
-- ignore all duplicate elements
let skipDupes pos = do
      jtem <- MV.read v pos
      if item == jtem
        then skipDupes (pos + 1)
        else return pos
pos <- skipDupes pos
```

If you want to test your code on various inputs, use
`Data.Vector.thaw`/`Data.Vector.freeze` to convert an `Vector a` to and from a
`MVector s a`.

As you run into issues, post the code you have so far and the errors you're
running into.